# javascript error: ReferenceError: edit is not defined edit(this);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, referenceerror

I have an html file, in which, i want to edit the fields.
Following is my html code :

```
  <body>
  <div class= "table">
  <div class = "thead">
  <div class = "tr">

    <div class = "td">ID</div>
   <div class = "td">GROUP NAME</div>
   <div class = "td">GROUP DESCRIPTION</div>
    <div class = "td">IS ACTIVE</div>
   <div class = "td"></div>
   <div class = "td"></div>
   </div>
   </div>

<div class= "tbody">
 <form  class = "tr">
   <div class = "td">1</div>
   <div class = "td">hello</div>
   <div class = "td">hwryou</div>
   <div class = "td">y</div>
   <div class = "td action" ><button type="button "onclick="edit(this);">edit</button>     </div>
  <form>
   </div>
  </div>
   </body>
```

following is my javascript code :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="serialize-0.2.min.js">

 function edit(element){
    var tr = jQuery(element).parent().parent();
    if(!tr.hasClass("editing")) {
            tr.addClass("editing");
            tr.find("DIV.td").each(function(){
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){
                            var value = jQuery(this).text();
                            jQuery(this).text("");
                            jQuery(this).append('<input type="text" value="'+value+'"   />');
                    } else {
                            jQuery(this).find("BUTTON").text("save");
                    }
            });
    } else {
            tr.removeClass("editing");
            tr.find("DIV.td").each(function(){
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){
                            var value = jQuery(this).find("INPUT").val();
                            jQuery(this).text(value);
                            jQuery(this).find("INPUT").remove();
                    } else{ jQuery(this).find("BUTTON").text("edit");
                    }}); }
   }</script>
```

while creating the out put, when i click the edit button, it is showing the reference error edit is not defined.what may be reason for that?

**updated :**

i have an other requirement that, on clicking the save button, the changed content should be saved in the database.How can and where i should write the update query? also i required a delete button so that on clicking the delete button, an update command should run.HOw can i achieve this ?/

Comment: Aren't you missing a space here `type="button"onclick="edit(this);"`?

Comment: no in the actual code, space is there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A script can be inline or external, it cannot be both.

The presence of the `src` attribute causes the text node children of the script node to be ignored.

If you want inline and external scripts, use two script elements.

```
<script src="serialize-0.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function edit(element){
    // etc
```

Comment: i used like this, but it showing the error :ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
[Break On This Error]  

var tr = jQuery(element).parent().parent();

Comment: You are calling jQuery. You must include the jQuery library with a `<script>` element before you can do that.

Comment: i had an another requirement, that i mentioned in my query. could you please help me in doing that?

Comment: @Jenifer_justin — That's a completely different problem. [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="serialize-0.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function edit(element){
  // Your Code 
}
</script>
```

Try this.

Comment: if you had explained why it would be an acceptable solution ;)